# wrong cwd in python mode

Tags: python

When i do `C-c C-c` on a python module, it leads to `*Python*` buffer with Inferior Python : run Shell-Compile mode. 
Suppose the correct cwd is `/x/y/z/`
The problem is when I print `os.getcwd()`, i get wrong cwd = `/x/y/`
Due to this, modules from the same directory can not be imported.

But when i run `M-x run-python` from the same module, `os.getcwd()` is fine and modules can be imported.

Anyone knows what is happening here ?

Comment: `C-c C-c` (`python-shell-send-buffer`) sends code to the existing buffer. So I guess you'd already created a buffer in that other directory. What do you want to do? Change the directory of the existing buffer (which may have been used for different, even incompatible stuff)? Have separate Python buffers for each file? for each directory?

Comment: `C-c C-c` interprets the code but can not import any modules from the same directory. `os.getcwd()` in the same interpreter buffer gives wrong directory - this is why the modules from same directory could not be imported. Now i kill this `*Python*` buffer and run `M-x run-python`. Now `os.getcwd()` runs just fine. Running `C-c C-c`  also interprets and imports all modules since cwd is correct now. Why this cwd difference between `C-c C-c` and `M-x run-python` ?

Comment: `C-c C-c` sends code to the existing buffer. If the existing buffer was created from a file in a different directory, the existing buffer is in that different directory. If the existing buffer was created from a file in the same directory, the existing buffer is in the same directory.

Comment: `*Python*` buffer doesn't exist. `C-c C-c` is run on a file in a directory `/x/y/z/`. `os.getcwd()` in this buffer returns `/x/y/` instead of `/x/y/z/`. Killing this `*Python*` buffer, creating the new `*Python*` buffer with `M-x run-python` from the same file same directory and `os.getcwd()` returns correct `/x/y/z/` now and modules from the same directory are getting imported. Wasn't `C-c C-c` also supposed to do the same thing and import the modules from the same directory ?

Comment: `Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native-enable’ was t and "python" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally. `
Also i am getting this warning when i run `C-c C-c` on my python code.

Comment: Oh. What version of Emacs do you have? I have 25.2 and `C-c C-c` tells me “user-error: Start a Python process first with ‘M-x run-python’ or ‘C-c C-p’.” if there's no `*Python*` buffer. It makes sense that `C-c C-c` would be improved to create `*Python*` if it doesn't exist. But what do you expect to happen if the buffer already exists?

Comment: Yes if the buffer was created by using `M-x run-python`. Running `C-c C-c` sends my code to this buffer and runs fine. But when i configured Emacs for python running `C-c C-c` created a new `*Python*` buffer if it wasn't existing and interpreted my code. But I don't know some Emacs update or something else broke this feature. Now `C-c C-c` creates the buffer but with incorrect cwd. I have Emacs 26.2. I just want to know why this is happening and what can be done to make `C-c C-c` work like it did before ?

Answer (score 2):

If the `elpy-shell-starting-directory` variable is set to `project-root` then you will see the behaviour described. That is, the default directory for the Python shell is `/x/y`, the root of `/x/y/z`. Thus while editing code in a project `z`, it makes sense to run the code from `y`.

To get what you want, set `current-directory` as the value of `elpy-shell-starting-directory`.

So "`M-x customize-variable elpy-shell-starting-directory`", change to `current-directory`, and then apply and save for future sessions.

This will add the following to `~/.emacs-custom`

```
 '(elpy-shell-starting-directory (quote current-directory))
```